# 2nd order Runge-Kutta for 1st order quadratic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, runge-kutta-methods

I can't solve the following ODE with Runge-Kutta.

$$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=32-2v^{2}, \quad v(0)=3.8$$

with step size $h=0.1$. Could someone help me?

Comment: I can't find the K2

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context. This is easily solvable analytically, aren't you interested in an analytical solution? Also what is $K_2$?

Answer (score 1):

For the DE

$$
y'=f(y,t)\Rightarrow\cases{k_1=f(y_j,t_j)\\
k_2=f(y_j+k_1\frac h2, t_j+\frac h2)\\
y_{j+1}= y_j+k_2 h}
$$

here $f(y,t) = f(v) = 32-2v^2$ then

$$
\cases{
k_1 = 32-2v_j^2\\
k_2 = 32-2(v_j+k_1\frac h2)^2\\
v_{j+1} = v_j + k_2 h
}
$$

Follows a plot with $h=0.05$

[image]